# &&& operator as codeblock glue

Tags: javascript, c++, ruby, operator-overloading

Is there a way to make &&& behave as an operator which can concat operations into one codeblock?

This is something that came up to my mind while coding and was wondering if I could implement it somehow.

What I'm trying to achieve is make code more concise.
Example:

```
 for (i=0;i<n;++i)
    arr[i][0]+=2; &&& arr[i][1]+=3; &&& arr[i][2]=45;
```

I do not want to hear about how I can use additional for loop or use { } instead.

I'm wondering if such operator is possible in c++, javascript or (if not in one of those 2) in ruby

EDIT: I was aware that this is a bad thing to do but I was wondering if it is possible to be done nevertheless.
I though this was the whole point of having fun while coding.

Comment: Adding a `{}` would not only be more understandable, it's also **less typing**. Why make yourself type more?

Comment: How is your code more concise than anything?

Comment: There is always the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) but that would not be very maintainable code.

Comment: I guess you can simply use `&&` or `and` for that purpose in most of languages.

Comment: @Bartosz Only if the assigned values are always not `0`.

Comment: True, in Ruby `0` is not falsy though.

Comment: why do you specify the *ruby* lang?

Comment: +1: Just because it's a bad idea doesn't mean it's a bad question.

Comment: As it is clear what you want to do, I will answer for ruby: `(arr[0]=1) && (arr[1]=false) && arr[2]=3`. I think it may work with js, but I am not sure. On other hand, `&&&` is harder to make. You can use: `class Store;
  define_method "&&&" do |*args|;
    some_stuffs="that you want to do implement here";
  end;
end;  Store.new.send "&&&", 2, 3, 4, 5` but it would be messy.

Comment: While it might seem like "fun while programming" it also would be a lot less fun to anyone who ran into it while trying to use, or maintain, your code. Having the ability to override methods and/or create new ones, is a double-edge sword. If it truly improves things then it's cool. If it confuses people it should be avoided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `,` operator instead:

```
arr[i][0]+=2, arr[i][1]+=3, arr[i][2]=45;
```

But this is a very ugly way to code (and so is your proposal). Introducing a block and having each as a separate statement would be much easier to read.

Answer (score 6):

Well, `&&&` is lexed as `&&` followed by `&`, so you could overload the `&&` operator taking a pointer:

```
struct X
{
    int x;

    X& operator=(int i)
    {
        x = i;
        return *this;
    }

    X& operator+=(int i)
    {
        x += i;
        return *this;
    }

    X& operator&&(X*)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, operator precedence gets in the way, so you have to parenthesize the assignments:

```
int main()
{
    const int n = 10;
    X arr[n][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        (arr[i][0]+=2) &&& (arr[i][1]+=3) &&& (arr[i][2]=45);
    }
}
```

(But of course nobody in their right mind would actually use abominations like this in production code.)

Comment: +1 for "...nobody in their right mind would actually use abominations like this in production code"

Answer (score 1):

It is not part of the language definition, so no - you cannot arbitrarily define new syntax - that would be a *different language*.  You could create a preprocessor or translator to convert your *new language* to valid C++, but I hardly see what purpose this would serve on its own.